# Trying to get an animated object to jump in Java

Tags: java

You are now going to write the various methods in WizardController that animate the wizards. In order to follow the motion of the wizards properly you will need to slow the animation down. To help you do this we have provided a class method delay() in the WizardController class.
WizardController.delay(100);

So the question is write a public class method jump() that returns nothing. It should make the wizard passed as argument jump up one cell position from its current cell then return to its original cell. I have tried the code below and it compiles but not 100% sure if its correct..

```
  public static void jump(Wizard wizard1)
  {
wizard1.up();
WizardController.delay(1000);
wizard1.down(1);
}
```

...also I need to create an instance of wizard and execute the jump() method passing it as argument to check this works as expected. This I am unsure how to do.

here is the full code:

```
public class WizardController

{
   /**
    * instance variables
    */  

   private Wizard wizard1;
   private Wizard wizard2; 
   private int numOfRepeats;

   private static final int MIN_NUM_REPEATS = 1;
   private static final int MAX_NUM_REPEATS = 3;  

   public static final int LAST_CELL = 11;   

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class WizardController.
    */
   public WizardController(Wizard aWizard1, Wizard aWizard2)
   {
      super();
      this.wizard1 = aWizard1;
      this.wizard2 = aWizard2; 
      this.numOfRepeats = 0;      
   }

   /* instance methods */  
   /**
    * Prompts the user for a number of action repeats
    * in the range 1 to 3 inclusive, and returns this number.
    */
   public int promptForNumOfRepeats()   
   {
     int moves;    
     moves = Integer.parseInt(OUDialog.request("Please enter the number of" 
         + " action repeats to be performed - between 1 and 3 (inclusive)"));

          try
     {
        moves = Integer.parseInt(OUDialog.request("Please enter the number of" 
          + " action repeats to be performed - between 1 and 3 (inclusive)"));
     }

     catch (NumberFormatException anException)
     {
        moves = 0;
     }

     return moves;
   }  

    /**
    * Returns true if the argument is in the range 1 to 3 (inclusive),
    * otherwise false.
    */
   public boolean isValidNumOfRepeats(int aNumber)
   {
      return ((aNumber >= WizardController.MIN_NUM_REPEATS)
      && (aNumber <= WizardController.MAX_NUM_REPEATS));
   }   

   /**
    * Repeatedly prompts the user for a number of repeats of the moves, 
    * until they enter a valid input representing a number in the range 1 to 3
    * inclusive, and  then returns this number.
    */    
   public int getNumOfRepeats()
   {
      int repeats = this.promptForNumOfRepeats();
      while (!this.isValidNumOfRepeats(repeats))
      {
         OUDialog.alert("That is not a valid number of game repeats");
         repeats = this.promptForNumOfRepeats();    
      }
      return repeats; 
   }   
  public static void jump(Wizard wizard1)
  {
wizard1.up();
WizardController.delay(1000);
wizard1.down(1);
}

 public static void delay(int ms)
   {
      try{
         Thread.sleep(ms);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Problem in delay methods");
      }
   }
}
```

here is the Wizard class for any wxtra help:

```
public class Wizard
{  
   /* instance variables */
   private Triangle persona;  
   private int startCellX;
   private int startCellY; 
   private OUColour startColour;
   public static final int CELL_SIZE_X = 20;
   public static final int CELL_SIZE_Y = 30;

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Wizard
    */
   public Wizard(OUColour aColour, int cellY)
   {
      super(); 
      this.persona = new Triangle(30, 30, aColour);
      this.persona.setXPos(0);      
      this.persona.setYPos(cellY * Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y);
      this.startCellX = 0;
      this.startCellY = cellY;
      this.startColour = aColour;
   }


    /* instance methods */    
    /**
    * returns the persona of the Wizard - so that it can be displayed
    * in the graphical display window
    */
   public Triangle getPersona()
   {
      return this.persona;
   }

   /**
    * Resets the receiver to its "home" X position of 0.
    */
   public void homeX()
   {
      this.persona.setXPos(this.startCellX * Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X);
   }

   /**
    * Resets the receiver to its "home" Y position of startCellY * CELL_SIZE.
    */
   public void homeY()
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(this.startCellY * Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y);
   }

   /**
    * Decrements the X position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE.
    */
   public void left()
   {
      this.persona.setXPos(this.persona.getXPos() - Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X);
   }

   /**
    * Increments the X position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE.
    */
   public void right()
   {
      this.persona.setXPos(this.persona.getXPos() + Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X);
   }   

   /**
    * Decrements the Y position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE.
    */
   public void up()
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(this.persona.getYPos() - Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y);
   }

   /**
    * Increments the Y position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE.
    */
   public void down()
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(this.persona.getYPos() + Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y);
   }

   /**
    * Decrements the X position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE
    * times the value of the argument.
    */
   public void leftBy(int numCells)
   {
      this.persona.setXPos(this.persona.getXPos() - Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X * numCells);
   }

   /**
    * Increments the X position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE
    * times the value of the argument.
    */
   public void rightBy(int numCells)
   {
      this.persona.setXPos(this.persona.getXPos() + Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X * numCells);
   }


   /**
    * Decrements the Y position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE
    * times the value of the argument.
    */
   public void upBy(int numCells)
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(this.persona.getYPos() - Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y * numCells);
   }

   /**
    * Increments the Y position of the receiver by CELL_SIZE
    * times the value of the argument.
    */
   public void downBy(int numCells)
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(this.persona.getYPos() + Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y * numCells);
   }

   /**
    * returns the cellX the wizard is currently on
    */
   public int getCellX()
   {
      return this.persona.getXPos()/ Wizard.CELL_SIZE_X;
   }

   /**
    * returns the cellY the wizard is currently on
    */
   public int getCellY()
   {
      return this.persona.getYPos()/ Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y;
   }

   /**
    * sets the cellY the wizard is  on to the argument
    */
   public void setCellY(int aCellNumber)
   {
      this.persona.setYPos(aCellNumber * Wizard.CELL_SIZE_Y);
   }

    /**
    * Returns a string representation of the receiver.
    */
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "An instance of class " + this.getClass().getName() 
      + "  in cell X:" + this.getCellX()  + ", Y:" + this.getCellY()
      + ",  colour " + this.persona.getColour();
   }
```

Comment: have you executed it? does it do what it's supposed to do? if so, it works, if not, it doesn't

Comment: i executed this... Wizard w = new Wizard(OUColour.PINK, 1);
Triangle t = w.getPersona();
WizardController.jump(w);.... but I dont know if I did it correctly

Comment: `wizard1.down(1);` there is no `down(int)`method. Either use `down()`or `downBy(1)`

Comment: @jhamon and upBy(1)?

Comment: @Sak, well, look at your code: `public void upBy(int numCells)`